# QC 10: Shortcut keys for blocking a single step/all the steps?

Tags: quality-center

I am looking for shortcut Keys which can be used during execution. Below are the keys that I am aware of. Hope this helps:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: Begin Run
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: All Test Steps Pass
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: 1selected step pass
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>: All test Steps Fail
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: 1 selected test fails
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: End the execution run and saves the run result.

I am looking for a shortcut key which can be used for:

1. Blocking a single step
2. Blocking all the steps.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which test automation tool you are talking about? Doesn't it have a Help file with keyboard shortcuts described in it?

Comment: I am using QC 10.00 and I searched in the Help part, but was not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an HP Quality Centre request, these are the available shotcuts as of version 9.2:

***Test Lab Module Shotcuts***

**Test Lab Module**

```
ALT+N - Creates a new test set
CTRL+A - Adds test to test set
CTRL+DELETE - Removes test from test set
CTRL+F9 - Runs test
CTRL+ALT+F9 - Runs test manually
CTRL+SHIFT+F9 - Continues manual run
ALT+F9 - Runs test set
```

**Test Runner Module**

```
CTRL+Q - Ends the run
CTRL+R - Begins the run
CTRL+K - Cancels the run
CTRL+U - Adds attachments to the test run 
CTRL+B - Adds a new defect
CTRL+S - Adds attachments to the test step
CTRL+P - Passes the selected test run steps
CTRL+F - Fails the selected test run steps
CTRL+A - Passes all the test run steps
CTRL+G - Fails all the test run steps
CTRL+UPARROW/CTRL+DOWNARROW - Selects the previous or next test step
```

They may well have added more/tweaked some in later versions.  Generally have a look at Appendix B in the user manual.

***Edit** - Expanding answer*

To be clear my answer boils down to **There is no documented way in QC to do this as of 9.2** (and I'm pretty sure that hasn't changed in 10.0).

As QC is a HTML based application you could view the html source to double check this for yourself, see the following to see how accesskeys/hotkeys are added to html:

- http://techsupt.winbatch.com/TS/T000002021F3.html
- http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. But I am looking for shortcut keys to block test steps while running the test through a manual runner in HP QC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs, will try and add the Hotkeys.

Comment: Unless you can access the QC source you won't be able to add hotkeys, the examples I gave above are to show you what they look like to aid you in finding hotkeys that are already in the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

I tried accessing the source for QC, but when the manual run pop-up block opens, I cannot access the source. So, I guess would have to do with selecting the respective test cases for blocking them. But thanks a lot, for the info about adding hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

For blocking single statement, use keyword `rem` before the statement.

For blocking all statements, select all statements and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

To Unblock all statements, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.